# Why is React generator function with Yield not waiting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, generator, redux-saga

In a React app, I do not understand why the Yield line in a generator function is not 'waiting'? Specifically, in the LOGIN function below, I would expect the Yield line immediately following **console.log("Step 3")** to *pause* until it was completed; however it does NOT pause and Step 8 is immediately processed. I would expect the STEPS in the console.log to follow the logical numerical order.  The actual order that is printed out in the browser console window is: **1,2,3,8,9,10,4,5,6,7**.   Can someone explain why it is NOT pausing?

```
export function* LOGIN({ payload }) {
  const { email, password } = payload

  yield put({
    type: 'user/SET_STATE',
    payload: {
      loading: true,
    },
  })

  let userCog
  try {
    console.log("Step 1")
    userCog = yield call(login, email, password)
    console.log("Step 2")
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === 'UserNotConfirmedException') {
      yield put({
        type: 'user/SET_STATE',
        payload: {
          loading: true,
          email,
        },
      })
      yield history.push('/system/verification')
    }
  }
  console.log("Step 3")
  yield put({
    type: 'user/LOAD_CURRENT_ACCOUNT',
  })

  console.log("Step 8")
  if (userCog) {
    console.log("Step 9")
    yield history.push('/dashboard/analytics')
    console.log("Step 10")
  }
}

export function* LOAD_CURRENT_ACCOUNT() {
  yield put({
    type: 'user/SET_STATE',
    payload: {
      loading: true,
    },
  })

  console.log("Step 4")
  const response = yield call(currentUser)
  console.log("Step 5")
  if (response) {
    const { username } = response
    yield put({
      type: 'user/SET_STATE',
      payload: {
        id: '123',
        name: 'Administrator',
        email: username,
        role: 'admin',
        authorized: true,
      },
    })
  }
  console.log("Step 6")
  yield put({
    type: 'user/SET_STATE',
    payload: {
      loading: false,
    },
  })
  console.log("Step 7")
}
```

EDIT: Here is the redux dispatch from the Login UI Component

```
 onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { form, dispatch } = this.props
    form.validateFields((error, values) => {
      if (!error) {
        dispatch({
          type: 'user/LOGIN',
          payload: values,
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Please show us how you are calling these generator function. It doesn't seem to be a react-specific thing.

Comment: I added the Login UI Component that has the redux dispatch to the LOGIN function. Is that what was needed?

Comment: You better read more saga docs. `put` effect is non blocking while `call` effect is blocking.see https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#blocking--non-blocking

Comment: Generators are not equal to `async/await`!

Comment: I think you are not using saga correctly, every saga should be listening to action with `take` effect or similar.it seems you call saga like thunk. To me it seems you have a big knowledge gap. So please read some saga docs and understand the basics no miracles here.